# Creating a 3D version of the rule 90 cellular automaton

Tags: homework, cellular-automata

I need help. I want to create a 3D version of the rule 90 cellular automaton, but I don't know how to do it. Please help me. It is for a class in the theory of chaos.

[image]

this is my code

```
Autom90[lst_, t_] :=
  Module[{MR1, MR2, up2, up},
    MR1[ls_] := RotateRight[ls, 1];
    MR2[ls_] := RotateRight[ls, -1];
    up2[0, 0, 1] := 1;
    up2[0, 1, 1] := 1;
    up2[1, 0, 0] := 1;
    up2[1, 1, 0] := 1;
    up2[_, _, _] := 0;
    Attributes[up2] = Listable;
    up[ls_] := up2[MR1[ls], ls, MR2[ls]];
    NestList[up, lst, t]]

au = 
  Autom90[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 50]

Clear[delt, n, cel, cel2];
n := 100;
t := 100;
delt[1, n + 1] := 1;
delt[1, _] := 0;
lista := Table[delt[1, i], {i, 2 n + 1}];
au = Autom90[lista, t];
cel[i_, j_] := au[[i, j]];
cel2 := Table[cel[i, j], {i, t}, {j, 2*n + 1}];
ArrayPlot[cel2, ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, 0 -> Green}]
```

Comment: Is there nothing in the functionality of the [`CellularAutomaton`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellularAutomaton.html) function that can help you?

Comment: I have to use this code for do it in 3D :(